# Idiomatic implementation of a producer-streamer golang app

Tags: go, channel

I am in need of some advice here w.r.t implementation and testing of a design for an app I am currently working on. The primary design consideration is to stream a list of events from a server (my app) to clients. In order to accomplish that,

- I have a steady channel which is instantiated when the app starts and the publisher continues to push events to this channel indefinitely.
- A "reader" reads objects from this channel and streams it to the clients

The application code looks something like this:

```
type ApplicationService interface {
    ListEvents([]event.Event)   
}
type Application struct {
    ...
    EventChan chan event.Event
}
func NewApp() *Application {
    EventChan: make(chan event.Event),
}
// ListEvents is a producer for EventChan
func (app *Application) ListEvents(eventList []event.Event) {
    for _, e := range eventList {
        app.EventChan <- e
    }
}

// reader in another package
func read(app *Application) {
    go func() {
        for e := range app.EventChan {
            log.infof("Event: %v", e)
            // stream events
        }
    }()
}
```

When writing tests for the app, I got into trouble. During testing, I can use the ApplicationService interface to mock my app, but I can't get hold of `EventChan` unless I expose it somehow with the interface. (Should the interface have a getter-like function to expose the channel - but then the interface is no longer defining a behavior, isn't it? Or is there a better way to mock the `Application`)

My broader question is if this is right way to go about designing the app or can I refactor it to make it more *"go-esque"*.

Comment: If you need to access the `EventChan` in your tests, you still can type assert to `*Application` and access it because it is exported.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yeah, but then the `ApplicationService` interface is moot. I am using the interface mock for testing.